# Translucent navigation bar

Tags: android, material-design

I want to have the content of my layout being displayed under the navigation bar (also called translucent navigation bar). After reading on the internet, it says all you have to do is add this 2 items to style applied to the activity:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

The result is, that the navigation bar is light gray and not transparent. How do all the people solve this ?

Comment: Do you want it translucent or do you want it hidden?

Comment: I want it to be translucent, btw: I use Android Studio and let it create a basic activity for my project with CoordinatorLayout and so on predefined

Comment: Can noone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was the attribute

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in the root view of my layout (in this time CoordinatorLayout). This attribute prevents the content of the layout to draw behind the status and navigation bar.