# React Native Android Navigation Bar Translucent

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to set the navigation bar to translucent on android.
Take a look at the image for example:

 
[image]
<sub>(source: [morenews.pk](https://www.morenews.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/S8-navigation-bar.jpg))</sub>

I tried using `react-native-navigation-bar-color` but it only allows me to hide nav bar / show nav bar / change the color of nav bar.
So using this navigation bar library, I attempted to set `changeNavigationBarColor('transparent');` but it made my app crash.

I've also tried setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` which I brought from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237539/translucent-navigation-bar), but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: What was the crash? Maybe that is the way to do it but you need to dig in a bit?

Comment: @doubleA the app crashes with no warning or exception as soon as I reload after I set `changeNavigationBarColor('transparent');`

Comment: Have you tried this changeNavigationBarColor('#ffffffff',true)? It has 8f whereas the last two denotes the Alpha Channel.

Comment: @Ashwin Mothilal I've tried this trick before, Unfortunately no luck with this as well...

Comment: @Rondev Double check logcat. What you are describing is a fatal error from Android OS. No error message in RN nothing popping up on screen is a fatal crash. That should be in Logcat in AS.

Comment: did you find a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069070/completely-transparent-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-on-lollipop

Answer (score 4):

A good way to get a translucent navigation and status bar is to add 3 style items to **android > app > src > main > res > values > styles.xml**

These will set the bottom navigator bar to translucent:
`<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`
`<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>`

This one sets the top status bar to translucent:
`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

Example of implementation in styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

        <!-- Make status & navigation bar translucent -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This will make your content render below the status and navigation bar.
To fix this you can use `react-native-safe-area-context` to get the safe area insets.

Example for a safe content view:

```
import { SafeAreaInsetsContext } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
const ContentView = (props) => {
    const safeInsets = useContext(SafeAreaInsetsContext);
    return (
        <View
            style={[
                {
                    marginLeft: safeInsets?.left,
                    marginTop: safeInsets?.top,
                    marginRight: safeInsets?.right,
                    marginBottom: safeInsets?.bottom
                }
            ]}
        >
            {props.children}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I took a look into the module and what it's doing and found that it's just using the native android `Color` library to parse the string.
(Docs for it can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color)

I was able to get the nav bar transparency using the `#AARRGGBB` pattern specified in the docs. 3 or 4 letter Hex strings are not supported, and rgb strings are not supported. Some color names are listed as supported but `transparent` is not one of them.

Unfortunately, even though I was able to set the nav bar to be fully transparent, I wasn't able to get the app to actually draw anything behind it, so fully transparent actually just ends up being white, and anything in between is a transparency relative to that white background.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party I guess but what worked for me today, using expo, is found at https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/

do `npx expo install expo-navigation-bar`

then add the following in your `App.js` file before the function block:

```
// enables edge-to-edge mode
NavigationBar.setPositionAsync('absolute')
// transparent backgrounds to see through
NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync('#ffffff00')
// changes the color of the button icons "dark||light"
NavigationBar.setButtonStyleAsync("dark");
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to accept string values. Would you like to try this?

```js
changeNavigationBarColor('rgba(0,0,0,0)',true)
```

Comment: Looks like this function only accepts hex as a string, because this line also makes the app crash without any warning or exception

Answer (score 0):

We need to make custom navigation bar and add safe area to it.And then give your required colour to safe area. Below, is the example,

```
<ImageBackground style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'silver'}} source={require('./des.jpeg')}>
<SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}/>

</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: I'm already using this trick as a temporary alternative. But this still doesn't make the navigation bar translucent

Comment: I have added a background image and tried making safearea transparent , its working for me , have updated the code in previous answer please check whether it is working for you or not

Comment: Can you please provide your full code? It doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Send me you code if possible so that i''ll better get the idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

You just add this lines to app.json:

```
"androidNavigationBar": {
  "visible": "sticky-immersive"
},
```